# Design Client - Server Application Java SE

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

I have a client - server application, Java SE and simple JDBC. I have one doubts about design my apps. I have a following server code:

```
    public void runServer() throws IOException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("configuration\\server-settings.txt"))) {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine()));
        while (run) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            executorService.execute(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket));
        }
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
        closeServerSocket();
    }
}
```

In above code I have a executor service for max 10 threads. Previously in execute method, when client connected I pass new Thread for this client. Example like this:

```
    -   public void run() {
-       try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
-               ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
-           while (true) {
-               try {
-                   sendObject = (BaseSendObject) ois.readObject();
-                   command = sendObject.getCommand();
-                   action.invoke(sendObject, oos);
-               } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | SQLException e) {
-                   LOGGER.error("Application error", e);
-               }
-           }
-       } catch (IOException ex) {
-           LOGGER.error("Error while creating server", ex);
-       }
-   }
```

But I think is bad idea because I keep the connection with client, and I can max only 10 clients connected at the same time to my app. 
My client app when started, only once invoke connect method to server:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server, Integer.parseInt(port));
```

After refactor code I write this run method in WorkerRunnable in my server:

```
    public void run() {
    try (ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
         ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
        invokeActionStrategy(objectOutputStream, objectInputStream);
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while creating server", ex);
    }
}
```

I only handle one client request and close connection with this client. In this case I not keep connect with one client in while loop. But in this case when my client must always before sending information to server re-establish connection to server:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(server, Integer.parseInt(port));
```

But I don't now is this good design for client -server app?

1. Create for each connected client thread to handle requests? But this approach is bad, beacause I can only 10 clients connected to server.
2. Connect client with server always when client wan't send request to handle. This is not bad performance design if I always after request invoke method to connect client to server?

What approach is best? Maybe other solution? If you have a better example or solution please explain in this topic.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use HTTP or messaging? Spring MVC or Ratpack would make this simple.

Comment: That's not special reason. This is my old project and I want refactor this. This is client - server desktop app.